# jQuery FullCalendar plugin title outside calendar container

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In FullCalendar plugin is possible to define title, where can see dates from.. till.. (Showing events 23.04.2013 - 25.04.2013). This can be done with following:

```
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
}
```

Is there some way to extract `title` for use in other element? I need to show this title contents out of `#calender` container.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take it with jquery

```
var title = $(".fc-header-title h2").html();
```

Comment: It would be ok, if use header:{center:'title'}, but I don't want to show it. So I need some different solution. Thanks!

Comment: ok, not the most professional way but I am not sure that there is another way of extracting it, so I would just css hide the `fc-header-title h2`,  and get the value from it with js

Comment: How I didn't saw/knew it before :) Thank you!

Comment: I found a little better solution `viewDisplay: function (view) {jQuery('.where_to_put_title').html(view.title);}
`